# How to make a link expire after click

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Basically, I have an email service with a "forget password" functionality. There is a link being sent to the specified user that wants to reset their password.

What I want is to make that link expires after the user clicks on it (has been used).

I am using C#'s MVC, and webforms. I can't share the code for privacy purposes, unfortunately.

Any ideas?

Comment: The unique part is usually some key that's passed as a parameter in the URL. That key would be associated with a user. Just disassociate it and dispose of the key. Your question doesn't provide near enough detail to know how your link is actually composed or works though, so hard to say. Provide enough detail for people to be able to give you meaningful answers.

Comment: 1: generate unique token - maybe a guid; 2: store it somewhere, usually with an expiry; 3: when the page is visited (with the token in the url), check the token (and what it means), and **kill it** (logical or physical delete); 4: there is no 4

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a stateful token.

What this means is you'll create a random guid (could be based on username, but still random).

Store that guid in a user/password linked table with the created date time and expiry time.

send the link with guid (http://emailsite.com/?token={random guid})

when the link is clicked, on page load, check the random guid param against the database.

if it doesn't exist, no password reset allowed.  if it does exist and the current time is not > than expiry, allow password reset and delete the record.  If it's to old, just tell them it's expired and delete the row.

instead of deleting the record, you can set it to inactive using a tinyint column.